# VSCode + Ubuntu: Cannot enable Settings Sync, redirect URI won't open in VSCode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDyif.png)

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and I installed VSCode from the Snap Store. I'm trying to enable Settings Sync.

- VSCode properly opens Firefox, the default web browser, to GitHub where I'm able to authenticate my GitHub credentials.
- Firefox / Ubuntu is unable to open the redirect URI back in VSCode. It's not presenting VSCode as an option, and the System Handler isn't properly handing the auth request off to VSCode.

I have no way to enable Settings Sync at this point. Uncertain if this is an Ubuntu issue, a Firefox issue, or a VSCode from Snap Store issue.

Tried enabling Settings Sync in Ubuntu. Expected, post auth, to have Redirect URI lead me back to VSCode to complete setup. This did not happen.

Comment: I bet it's a Snap issue. Try installing it from deb.

Comment: @wjandrea I did indeed give this a shot, but that didn't end up resolving anything. Not sure if there was residual data leftover though, as when I opened the application after removing the Snap and installing it from the .deb, it launched quickly and opened to the same progress in the Welcome screen as when it was launched via the Snap.

Comment: do you see any useful looking info in VS Code's Output Panel's various channels? And what if you run `code` with `--verbose --log trace`?

Comment: @starball It doesn't appear to be a VScode issue in terms of the running application, but rather how it's installed and configured in Ubuntu. VScode properly opens the authentication page in my browser, but it's the redirection back to VScode that isn't working. This is an Ubuntu / VScode installation issue (I would imagine), and not something that's an issue at runtime that would produce logs.